# Accessing Python 3 type annotations for variables at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I would like to know if it's possible to access type annotations for variables at runtime the same way you can use the `__annotations__` entry in `inspect.getmembers()` for methods and functions.

```
> a:Optional[str]=None
> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>

> a:str=None
> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`locals()` and `globals()` keep track of annotations of variables in the `__annotations__` key.

```
>>> from typing import *
>>> a: Optional[int] = None
>>> locals()['__annotations__']
{'a': typing.Union[int, NoneType]}
>>> locals()['__annotations__']['a']
typing.Union[int, NoneType]
>>> 
>>> foo = 0
>>> bar: foo
>>> locals()['__annotations__']['bar']
0
>>>
>>> baz: List[str]
>>> locals()['__annotations__']['baz']
typing.List[str]
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [@TrebledJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549282/10871073), here's a helper function for REPL use:

```
>>> def get_annot(var: str) -> str:
        if var in globals():
            return globals()["__annotations__"].get(var, "Un-annotated Variable")
        else:
            return "Undefined variable"

>>> var: int = 5
>>> get_annot(var)
int
```

Looks in the globals dict for the variable and returns annotation if it is both defined *and* annotated.